# Does constructor in cpp doesnot return anything?

Tags: c++, oop

It is said that constructor doesnot return anything.But if constructor doesnot return anything, then how do this code segment works:
`*this=classname{args};`.
I hope someone could shed me some light on whats actually going under the hood.

A complete code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class hell {
private:
    int a{}, b{};
public:
    hell(int _a = 7, int _b = 8) : a{ _a }, b{ _b } {}

    void print() {
        cout << a << endl << b << endl;
    }

    void change() {
        *this = hell(4, 5);
    }
};

int main() {
    hell h;
    h.print();
    h.change();
    h.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"It is said that constructor doesn't return anything"* - *Always* cite who says what you claim. Regardless, you're creating a temporary object with `hell(4,5)`, then assigning said-same to `*this` . That's all. An expression doesn't have to have a `return` emblazoned somewhere to have a value.

Comment: If you try and put `return xxx;` in  a constructor you will get a compile error. Constructors are not regular functions and therefore do not return values like regular functions. Whether that means they do not return anything is debateable.

Comment: `classname{args}` I would not say it returns something. I would say it is something. It is a temporary object. This can be assigned to an object. The constructor is just called as part of the processes in creating the object but it is just part of the processes.

Comment: Technically a constructor doesn't return anything. It constructs an instance of a the class in whatever memory it is given. The allocation of the memory used here happens automatically and out of sight, assuming the compiler doesn't optimize it out of existance.

Comment: `classname{args};` - _"...A single-word type name followed by a braced-init-list is a prvalue of the specified type designating a temporary (until C++17)whose result object is (since C++17) direct-list-initialized with the specified braced-init-list...._" [Explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)

Comment: Constructors don't return anything. But you can assign the result of construction to something.

Comment: @ArthurBesse Are you sure it doesn't call `operator=(hell&&)`? Deleting the copy assignment operator will take the move assignment operator with it unless you explicitly [add it back in](https://godbolt.org/z/1z3Pzfjjh)

Comment: @NathanPierson seems you are right.

Comment: A constructor is a *special member function*.  It can only be invoked indirectly.  It does not return anything — you can do an early `return;` in the body, but you can't do a `return 7;`.  It can throw an exception.  Its role is to initialize the member variables so that the object is in a valid coherent state.  In some cases, a constructor can be elided, so relying on a constructor's side-effects can be a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement

```
*this = hell(4, 6);
```

does two things:

1. First it create a temporary and unnamed object of the class `hell`, initialized using the values you use to pass to a suitable constructor.
2. Then that temporary and unnamed object is copy-assigned to the object pointed to by `this`.

---

It's somewhat similar to this:

```
{
    hell temporary_object(4, 5);  // Create a temporary object
    *this = temporary_object;  // Copy the temporary object to *this
}
```

Comment: Isn't it more similar to `*this = std::move(temporary_object)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question must be about this line:

```
*this = hell(4,5);
```

This might look like a function call, calling the constructor function. But this is not a function call. This is (a particular) syntax for creating a new `hell` object, a temporary object. This is slightly outdated syntax, modern C++ prefers:

```
*this = hell{4, 5};
```

but it's the same thing.

This does call the constructor, but only as part of constructing a new object.

Once the temporary object gets constructed it gets assigned to `*this`. The End.

Comment: *"slightly outdated syntax"* A gross oversimplification. >:(

Comment: Well, if you want a bit of sophistry here, slap a `language-lawyer` tag on it...

Answer (score 1):

For better intuition, constructor can be called "initializator". This reveals more of it's main purpose. The constructor initializes object rather then creates. So the instance of the object is already present in the memory when the constructor is called. All it does is initializing it.

Comment: Meh. "Initializator" sounds way too similar to "initializer", which has its own different meaning.